# Need troubleshooting of shortcode attribute parsing

Tags: php, wordpress, datetime, parsing, shortcode

This is part of a complicated function I wrote 2 years ago and I can’t remember how to pass the date and time in the shortcode.
As a result, the post fails to publish.

I don’t see why it’s not working so I thought a fresh set of eyes might see  the reason.

Below is the problematic section of code, the shortcode in the post, and the debug log.

Please have a look and let me know if you see the reason. Thanks much!!

See arrow in code where error occurs at line 272 per debug log:

```
//Parse the attributes passed from the shortcode for use downstream. Use default where no attribute was passed. Ignore any passed attribute for which there is no default.
    $auc_start = $parsed_atts['auc_start'];
    $auc_end = $parsed_atts['auc_end'];
    $starting_bid = $parsed_atts['start_bid'];
    $bid_increment = $parsed_atts['bid_increment'];
    $human_answer = $parsed_atts['human_answer'];
    $math_sum = $parsed_atts['human_sum'];
    $sell_price = $parsed_atts['sell_price'];

    //Set the time zone for the auction
    date_default_timezone_set("America/Denver");
    //Assign current server time (which is a unix timestamp), adjusted for time zone, to a variable.
    $now = new DateTime();
    //Convert the auction START shortcode attribute (which is a date/time string) to a unix timestamp and assign to a variable.
LINE 272———->>  $auction_start = new DateTime("$auc_start");
    //Convert the auction END shortcode attribute (which is a date/time string) to a unix timestamp and assign to a variable.
    $auction_end = new DateTime("$auc_end");
```

This is what I am passing in the shortcode:

```
[jwp_auction auc_start=“2020-02-28 16:15:00" auc_end=“2020-03-01 16:15:00”]
```

This is the debug log content:

```
[28-Feb-2020 16:27:02 America/Denver] PHP Fatal error:  
Uncaught Exception: DateTime::__construct(): 
Failed to parse time string (“2020-02-28) at position 0 (�):
 Unexpected character in 
/var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/jwp_functionality_plugin/jwp_functionality_plugin.php:272

Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/jwp_functionality_plugin/jwp_functionality_plugin.php(272): DateTime->__construct('\xE2\x80\x9C2020-02-28')
#1 /var/www/html/wp-includes/shortcodes.php(325): bid_form_display(Array, '', 'jwp_auction')
#2 [internal function]: do_shortcode_tag(Array)
#3 /var/www/html/wp-includes/shortcodes.php(199): preg_replace_callback('/\\[(\\[?)(jwp_au...', 'do_shortcode_ta...', '\n<figure class=...')
#4 /var/www/html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(288): do_shortcode('\n<figure class=...')
#5 /var/www/html/wp-includes/plugin.php(206): WP_Hook->apply_filters('\n<figure class=...', Array)
#6 /var/www/html/wp-includes/rest-api/endpoints/class-wp-rest-posts-controller.php(1550): apply_filters('the_content', '<!-- wp:image {...')
#7 /var/www/html/wp-includes/re in /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/jwp_functionality_plugin/jwp_functionality_plugin.php on line 272
```

Comment: Dunno much about WP, but: `[jwp_auction auc_start=“2020-02-28 16:15:00" auc_end=“2020-03-01 16:15:00”]` <- you have different kind of double quotes in there (`“` and `"`), that seems quite odd. `"` is the basic/default double quote character and should probably be everywhere.

Comment: Thanks Jeto! I edited the quotes but am still getting the same errors. Anyone else have any ideas?

Comment: I found an extra space in a variable to get past this error. Now on the solve further ones :/

Comment: Which further ones? Please edit your question with updated info.

Comment: As it turns out, I am working through several errors not in question here. I will post a new question if assistance is needed regarding those. Also turns out the quotes you mentioned were causing the problem along with that additional space. Thanks Jets for catching that!